# Using Azure DevOps API to share a pull request

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would like to be able to use the Azure DevOps API to send emails about certain pull requests.

I am looking at this page as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20share/share%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I am not sure how the body of the POST should be formatted, especially the "IdentityRef" entry. How do I get this IdentityRef for individual users?

Comment: Hi @Sirch, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body format is like this

```
{
  "message": "xxx",
  "receivers": [
    {
      "id": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to share the pull request with individual user, you could get the user ID via this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/search%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you! I had the id, was just formatting the "receivers"  incorrectly.